# How to make a row into column in PENTAHO

Tags: pentaho

I have a file like this:

```
COUNTRY | 2008 | 2009 | 2010 | 2011 | 2012 | TYPE
SPAIN      5      41     8      12      5     T1
SPAIN      4      6       2      7      14    T2
SPAIN      7      8      9       6      2     T3
FRANCE     4      5      7       9      66    T1
FRANCE     14     3      4       12     12    T2
FRANCE     5      8      11       3      6    T3
...
```

And I need to convert it into a format like:

```
COUNTRY | YEAR | T1 | T2 | T3
SPAIN     2008   5    4    7
SPAIN     2009   41   6    8
....
```

Thanks

Comment: Tell us [what you've tried](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and where you are stuck. This will also help us answer your question better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're talking about Pentaho Data Integration you can use the Row Normalizer step. It allows you to define the columns that hold measure types, and convert them into a single "type" column.

Check the [documentation](https://help.pentaho.com/Documentation/8.2/Products/Data_Integration/Transformation_Step_Reference/Row_Normaliser) for examples of usage.